# I am getting this error from my bluetooth connected device Error: [BleError: Device 7C:CC:FC:B4:77:E9 is not connected]

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a react native application. This application uses the "ble-plx" library, which is the bluetooth low energy library. connection is fine on my first page. But on my second page, I am sending the connection parameter and other necessary parameters with the parameters. But on my first try, my console says that the bluetooth connection is disconnected. But when I use my disconnect function and disconnect, the next time I connect, the bluetooth connection works on the second page. I couldn't find any idea how to solve it. Thanks for your help in advance.

I tried to understand what I was doing on the first page but there is no sensible option

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add all relevant code to your question so others can help you. Check out [ask] and [mcve] when you can

Comment: @Abe thanks for your comment. I'll be more informative when asking questions from now on.By the way I fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you fixed your issue, it would be helpful to others if you posted the broken code in your question, and then feel free to answer and accept your own answer as the solution!